# How to refer to a custom slider inside a listview in Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin, slider, refer

I have a custom slider and have tried to put it inside a listview with grids so the listview displays the following: Top left: items from a list as strings. Bottom left: (under each item) the custom slider. (To the right/the second column: an int/number value for each item).

The custom slider is made with the NuGet package SkiaSharp and is called "x:Name="balloon_slider"".
My problem: When I put the custom slider inside my listview in xaml - it can no longer be refered to in the C# behind (does not exist in the current context). (It works outside the listview.)
Here is the xaml code for the listview:

```
                     <ListView x:Name="displaylist100" HasUnevenRows="True">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <!--Items from list as strings-->

                                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">                  
                                            <Label x:Name="listlabel"
                                                Text="{Binding Text}"
                                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                FontSize="Medium" 
                                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                Padding="10, 10"
                                                Margin="0,5,5,0"/>

                                            <!--SkiaSharp Balloon_slider-->

                                            <Grid>
                                            <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="balloon_slider"      
                                             PaintSurface="Handle_Slider_PaintSurface"/>
                                            <local:BalloonView x:Name="balloonSvg"/>
                                            <Grid.Effects>
                                                <local:TouchEffect        
                                                TouchAction="Handle_TouchAction"/>
                                            </Grid.Effects>
                                            </Grid> 

                                            <!--Value displayed to the right-->

                                            <Label Text="{Binding DisplayValue, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Padding="10, 10"
                                            Grid.Column="1"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

The slider that I'm using is a customized version of this: "https://github.com/memsranga/Balloony".

I have tried to use this: "var balloon_slider = (SKCanvasView)listView.FindByName("balloon_slider");" in the "InitializeComponent ();" section - but it doesn't seem to make it connect the two.
I have also tried to have a standard slider in the listview - which works. So my question is: how can I refer to the slider from my C# behind when it is in the listview?

Update:
Here is the code behind from the balloon slider project - I'm a bit confused about what I need to change in order to do the binding. Currently it is each "balloon_slider" and "balloonSvg" which has the error that it can't be found:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using static Balloony.TouchEffect;

namespace Balloony
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            SliderSelectedPaint = new SKPaint
            {
                Color = Color.FromHex("#eb0000").ToSKColor(),
                IsAntialias = true,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
                StrokeWidth = SliderHeight
            };

            SliderUnSelectedPaint = new SKPaint
            {
                Color = Color.FromHex("#f8f8f8").ToSKColor(),
                IsAntialias = true,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
                StrokeWidth = SliderHeight
            };

            ThumbPaint = new SKPaint
            {
                Color = Color.FromHex("#eb0000").ToSKColor(),
                IsAntialias = true,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill
            };
            ThumbSelectedPaint = new SKPaint
            {
                Color = Color.FromHex("#eb0000").ToSKColor(),
                IsAntialias = true,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
                StrokeWidth = SelectedThumbThickness
            };
            ThumbSelectedSubtractPaint = new SKPaint
            {
                Color = Color.Transparent.ToSKColor(),
                IsAntialias = true,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
                StrokeWidth = 0,
                BlendMode = SKBlendMode.Src
            };
            ThumbSubtractPaint = new SKPaint
            {
                Color = Color.Transparent.ToSKColor(),
                IsAntialias = true,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
                StrokeWidth = 0,
                BlendMode = SKBlendMode.Src
            };

            Percent = 50;
        }

        float SliderHeight = 5;
        float SelectedThumbThickness = 10;
        float ThumbSize = 50;
        SKPaint SliderSelectedPaint { get; set; }
        SKPaint SliderUnSelectedPaint { get; set; }
        SKPaint ThumbPaint { get; set; }
        SKPaint ThumbSubtractPaint { get; set; }
        SKPaint ThumbSelectedPaint { get; set; }
        SKPaint ThumbSelectedSubtractPaint { get; set; }
        private TouchActionType _touchType;
        private double _width;
        private float _percent;

        public float Percent
        {
            get => _percent;
            private set
            {
                _percent = value;
                balloon_slider.InvalidateSurface();
                TranslateBalloon(Percent);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

            // only calling when orientation changes
            if (Math.Abs(width - _width) > 0.01)
            {
                _width = width;
                balloonSvg.AnchorY = 1;
                balloonSvg.TranslationX = (balloon_slider.Width * Percent / 100) - balloonSvg.Width / 2;
                balloonSvg.Scale = 0;
                balloonSvg.TranslationY = balloon_slider.Height;
            }
        }

        void Handle_Slider_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            var info = e.Info;
            var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;

            canvas.Clear();

            DrawSlider(canvas, info, Percent);
            DrawThumb(canvas, info, Percent, _touchType);
        }

        private void TranslateBalloon(float percent)
        {
            if (this.AnimationIsRunning("TranslationAnimation"))
            {
                return;
            }

            var oldX = balloonSvg.TranslationX;
            var newX = balloon_slider.Width * percent / 100 - balloonSvg.Width / 2;
            balloonSvg.Text = Math.Floor(Percent).ToString();

            var translation = new Animation();
            translation.Add(0, 1, new Animation((s) =>
            {
                if (oldX > newX)
                {
                    var delta = oldX - s * Math.Abs(oldX - newX);
                    balloonSvg.TranslationX = delta;
                }
                else
                {
                    var delta = oldX + s * Math.Abs(oldX - newX);
                    balloonSvg.TranslationX = delta;
                }
            }, 0, 1));
            translation.Add(0, 1, new Animation(s =>
            {
                if (oldX > newX)
                {
                    var delta = oldX - s * Math.Abs(oldX - newX);
                    var angle = Math.Abs(oldX - newX) > 0.001 ? Math.Tanh((oldX - newX) / balloon_slider.Width) : 0;
                    balloonSvg.Rotation = angle * 180;
                }
                else
                {
                    var delta = oldX + s * Math.Abs(oldX - newX);
                    var angle = Math.Abs(oldX - newX) > 0.001 ? Math.Tanh((oldX - newX) / balloon_slider.Width) : 0;
                    balloonSvg.Rotation = angle * 180;
                }
            }, 0, 1, finished: () =>
            {
                balloonSvg.RelRotateTo(-balloonSvg.Rotation, 500);
            }));
            translation.Commit(balloonSvg, "TranslationAnimation", length: 100);
        }

        private void DrawThumb(SKCanvas canvas, SKImageInfo info, float percent, TouchActionType touchActionType)
        {
            var y = info.Height - ThumbSize - SelectedThumbThickness;
            var center = info.Width * percent / 100;

            if (touchActionType == TouchActionType.Pressed || touchActionType == TouchActionType.Moved)
            {
                // selected thumb
                var radius = ThumbSize * 0.5f; // 50% of size
                canvas.DrawCircle(center, y, radius, ThumbSelectedPaint);
                canvas.DrawCircle(center, y, radius, ThumbSelectedSubtractPaint);
                return;
            }

            //default thumb
            var startX = center - ThumbSize / 2;
            var startY = y - ThumbSize / 2;
            var cornerRadius = ThumbSize * 0.4f; // 40% of size
            var innerRadius = ThumbSize / 2 * .5f; // 50 % of side
            canvas.DrawRoundRect(startX, startY, ThumbSize, ThumbSize, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, ThumbPaint);
            canvas.DrawCircle(center, y, innerRadius, ThumbSubtractPaint);
        }

        private void Handle_TouchAction(object sender, Balloony.TouchEffect.TouchActionEventArgs args)
        {
            _touchType = args.Type;
            if (this.AnimationIsRunning("FloatAnimation") || this.AnimationIsRunning("DropAnimation"))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (_touchType == TouchActionType.Pressed || _touchType == TouchActionType.Entered)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("entered");
                var floatAnimation = new Animation();
                floatAnimation.Add(0, 1, new Animation((s) =>
                {
                    balloonSvg.Scale = s;
                    balloonSvg.TranslationY = (balloon_slider.Height - balloonSvg.Height - 88) - s * -45;
                }, 0, 1));
                floatAnimation.Commit(balloonSvg, "FloatAnimation");
            }
            else if (_touchType == TouchActionType.Released || _touchType == TouchActionType.Exited)
            {
                var dropAnimation = new Animation();
                dropAnimation.Add(0, 1, new Animation((s) =>
                {
                    balloonSvg.Scale = s;
                    balloonSvg.TranslationY = (balloon_slider.Height - balloonSvg.Height - 88) - s * -45;
                }, 1, 0));
                dropAnimation.Commit(balloonSvg, "DropAnimation");
            }
            Percent = (float)((args.Location.X / balloon_slider.Width) * 100 - 15);
            if (Percent > 100)
            {
                Percent = 100;
            }
            if (Percent < 0)
            {
                Percent = 0;
            }
            if (Percent < 20)
            {
                
            }
        }




        private void DrawSlider(SKCanvas canvas, SKImageInfo info, float percent)
        {
            var y = info.Height - ThumbSize - SelectedThumbThickness; // minus the thumb radius, minus thumb thickness
            percent = Math.Min(percent, 100);
            var selectX = info.Width * percent / 100;

            canvas.DrawLine(0, y, selectX, y, SliderSelectedPaint);
            canvas.DrawLine(selectX, y, info.Width, y, SliderUnSelectedPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been discussed a thousand times.  Elements inside templated controls cannot be referenced by name.  Just think about it - at runtime there may be 0, or a dozen, or a million instances of that slider created.  Which one would the `x:Name` refer to?  You need to use data binding to bind the slider's properties to properties in your model or VM.

Comment: Oh ok - sorry about that. I should look into MVVM some more - for some reason at first I thought that was something you would use when you were more skilled at coding - so I was trying to avoid it when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jason said, Elements inside templated controls cannot be referenced by Name.

If you add event to the `SKCanvasView`  inside of the ListView and implement this function in `YourPage.xaml.cs`, you can get the View's instance by the paramter `sender` .

Please refer to the following code:

```
      public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void balloon_slider_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        SKCanvasView  sKCanvasView = (SKCanvasView)sender;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In general, we recommend using `MVVM` and `data binding` to achieve this. For comparison, I added two buttons, one that responds to the click event using the `Command` method, and one that adds the `Clicked` event.

You can refer to the following code:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
   
        public ICommand RemoveItemCommand { get; set; }
   
        public MyViewModel() { 
         Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            Items.Add( new Item { NumType = "S" , LocationCode = "0001"});
            Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "M", LocationCode = "0002" });
            Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "L", LocationCode = "0003" });
            Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "S", LocationCode = "0001" });
            Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "M", LocationCode = "0002" });
            Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "L", LocationCode = "0003" });
  

            RemoveItemCommand = new Command<Item>(RemoveItem);
   
        }

        private void RemoveItem(Item obj)
        {
            if (Items != null && Items.Contains(obj))
            {
                Items.Remove(obj);
            }
        }
      
    }
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isChecked, value);
        }
    }

    public string NumType { get; set; }

    public string LocationCode { get; set; }


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:xamlistviewapp131="clr-namespace:XamListViewApp131"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             x:Class="XamListViewApp131.MainPage"
             >
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <xamlistviewapp131:MyViewModel></xamlistviewapp131:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

        <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical"
                      Spacing="25"
                      Padding="30,0"
                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                     >

        <ListView Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="listview"   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  >
                
                <ListView.Header>TheHeader</ListView.Header>
                
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding NumType}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LocationCode}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />
  
                            <Button Text="Remove" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding BindingContext.RemoveItemCommand, Source={x:Reference listview}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  />
                            
                            <Button Text="Test" Grid.Column="3" Clicked="Button_Clicked"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  />

                            <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="balloon_slider" Grid.Column="4"   BackgroundColor="Yellow"   WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"
                                             PaintSurface="balloon_slider_PaintSurface" />

                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void balloon_slider_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        SKCanvasView  sKCanvasView = (SKCanvasView)sender;

    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Item item= button.CommandParameter as Item;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("click item is: "+item.NumType);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have updated the question - do you know how I need to change the code - in order to make the binding work?